# Adding many objects in java

Tags: java, class, lwjgl

Correct me if i'm wrong. I am very new to java and am trying to create a simple physics engine using lwjgl. At the moment the code is a bit messy, but it starts and works correctly, and the physics work perfectly.I am trying to think of a way to allow the user to click their mouse and add a physics_object. Currently, it is possible, but with a limit, and i have to code in all the object names.

adding a physics object:

```
phys_square rec1 = new phys_square(100, 100, 10.0f, -1.0f, 10, 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
```

and the code for the phys_square class:

```
package quad;
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.input.Mouse;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;

public class phys_square {

float velocityY;
float velocityX;
int x;
int y;
int particleSize;
float red;
float green;
float blue;
public phys_square(int xpos, int ypos, float velocity_x, float velocity_y, int size, float red, float green, float blue) { this.x = xpos; this.y = ypos; this.velocityY = velocity_y; this.velocityX = velocity_x; this.particleSize = size; this.red = red; this.green = green; this.blue = blue;} 
public void updatePos() {
    if ( this.y == 0 | this.y < 0) {
        this.velocityY *= -0.825f;
    }
    if (this.y > 0 | this.y >= this.velocityY) {
        this.y -= this.velocityY;
        this.velocityY += 0.2f;
    }

    if (this.x <= 0 | this.x + quad_main.particleSize >= 800) {
        this.velocityX *= -0.5f;
    }
    if (this.x > 0 | this.x >= this.velocityX) {
        this.x -= this.velocityX;
        if (Math.abs(this.velocityX) <= 0){
            this.velocityX -= 0.2f;
        }
    }
    if (this.x < 0) {
        this.x = 0;
    }
    if (this.x > 800 + quad_main.particleSize) {
        this.x = 800 + quad_main.particleSize; 
    }
    if (this.y < 0){
        this.y = 0;
    }
}
public void render() {
    window.particle(this.x, this.y, this.red, this.green, this.blue, this.particleSize);
}
public static void main(String[] args[]){

}
}
```

Is there a way to create multiple objects without manually assigning them all names? I heard in PHP and some other languages it is possible to use the value of a string as the name of another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** this answer assumes that you don't need names at all, not that you want to create names at run time. Use a hash map for that.

You can store objects in a list, such as an `ArrayList`. This acts like an array of objects, but is resizeable and and gives you the ability to add them at will, access them using an index, and iterate through them.

---

Put this with your imports:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

The following code creates your `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<phys_square> squaresList = new ArrayList<phys_square>();
```

You can add an object to your `ArrayList` like this:

```
squaresList.add(new phys_square( /* paramenters here */));
```

When you want to process the objects, you can iterate through your list. The following code executes methods on every element of the list.

```
for (phys_square sq : squaresList) {
    processPhysicsStuff(sq);
    processGraphicsStuff(sq);
}
```

You can view the documentation for `Arraylist` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). Read up, it's a very useful class.